# Vue js: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at import line

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to use vue plugins but everytime I do I always get an Unexpected Identifier on the import line. Any suggestions?

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
  <h1>@{{ message }}</h1>
  <v-select :value.sync="selected" :options="options"></v-select>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#content',
    data: {
    message: 'Hello Worldy'
    },
    import vSelect from "vue-select"
    export default {
        components: {vSelect},
        data() {
          return {
            selected: null,
            options: ['foo','bar','baz']
          }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: if you're going to import anything, it should be done before and outside of the Vue instance declaration.

Comment: The error message is literally correct. You can't have an import/export statement there. You should revise ES6 syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `import` from where you're trying to

```
import vSelect from "vue-select"

new Vue({
  el: '#content',
  components: {
    vSelect: vSelect
  }
});
```

and then do the rest of it inside your component definition

Comment: Hello @darryn.ten, I'm importing from top but it's showing same. I've install Vue from NPM locally.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case another person encounter this same error sign in the console when using vue. As for me in my case, the import script was automatically created for one of the components I called in my Laravel blade template (by PhpStorm).

The importation is recommended to be called in the Js file where the instance of `Vue` is made, because of the need to compile `import syntax` of ES6 to ES5. See: https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/a-simple-intro-to-javascript-imports-and-exports-389dd53c3fac

Hope this helps someone save some time.

Answer (score 0):

When you insert tag, which is related to your Vue.js component, in your blade file, PhpStorm indeed like Oluwatobi Samuel Omisakin wrote inserts such code

```
     <script>
        import MyComponent from "../../../js/components/myComponent";
        export default {
           components: {MyComponent}
        }
     </script>
```

in the end of your blade file. And this is brings you error in console. Just delete it and make import in you app.js file.